# Valor gerado SHA2_512 desconfigurado no SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Pessoal estou tentando criar um token utilizando o SHA2_512 no SQL Server, mas ele sai todo desconfigurado.
O valor que está sendo gerado é: 'Í×¥ªvÈ ®AåMœ¬"ˆ˜ï@Âíïg“ä•]Ï+Ü‡§‘Ú›le‹Öm<p¸A¯•ç·Lqhò"?™¿­'

O que estou fazendo de errado?

```
ALTER Procedure [Administrativo].[spCriarUsuario](
    -- Parâmetros Obrigatórios
    @AspNetUserId varchar(256)
,   @EmpresaId int
,   @Nome varchar(100)
,   @Sobrenome varchar(100)
,   @TimeZone varchar(6)
,   @Usuario varchar(256)
)

 -- Abre a transação
 As Begin

 -- Declaração de variáveis
Declare @ValidarUsuario int;  -- retorna 0 ou 1 (Verifica se o usuário existe)
Declare @RetornaUsuarioId int; -- retornar o id do usuário
Declare @RetornaEmpresaId int; -- retornar o id da empresa do usuário que fez a requição.
Declare @TokenUsuario varchar(max); -- token dentro da tabela
Declare @TokenClaim varchar(max); -- token da tabela claim
Declare @NovoId int; -- atribui um novo id

-- Executa as funções
Set @ValidarUsuario = Administrativo.fnVerificarUsuario(@Usuario);
Set @RetornaUsuarioId = Administrativo.fnRetornarUsuarioId(@Usuario);
Set @RetornaEmpresaId = Administrativo.fnRetornarEmpresaId(@Usuario);
Set @TokenUsuario = (Select HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @AspNetUserId))


-- Validações
if(@Usuario is null)
Throw 51000, 'Por favor informar o usuário.', 1;

if(@ValidarUsuario = 0)
Throw 51000, 'Usuário inválido, tente novamente por favor!.', 1;

if(@ValidarUsuario is null)
Throw 51000, 'Usuario não existente, tente novamente por favor!.', 1;

-- Caso o usuário que fez a requizição não existe no banco.
if(@RetornaUsuarioId = 0)
Throw 51000, 'Não foi possível encontrar o usuário, tente novamente por favor!.', 1;

if(@RetornaEmpresaId = 0)
Throw 51000, 'Não é possível continuar sem empresa, tente novamente por favor!.', 1;

if(@TokenUsuario is null)
Throw 51000, 'Ocorreu um erro no token, tente novamente por favor!.', 1;

-- Bloco do insert
Insert Administrativo.Usuario(
    AspNetuserId
,   Token
,   EmpresaId
,   Nome
,   Sobrenome
,   TimeZone
,   UsuarioCriacao
,   UsuarioAlteracao
,   CriadoEm
,   ModificadoEm
)Values(
    @AspNetUserId
,   @TokenUsuario
,   1
,   @Nome
,   @Sobrenome
,   @TimeZone
,   @RetornaUsuarioId
,   @RetornaUsuarioId
,   GetDate()
,   GetDate()
)

-- Atribui um novo identificador sequencial
Set @NovoId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

-- Retorna para nossa lista o novo id.
Select @NovoId as Id

-- Executa outra proc
Set @TokenClaim = (Select NEWID())

If(@NovoId > 0)
Begin
    Exec Administrativo.spCriarClaims @AspNetUserId, 'Token', @TokenClaim, @Usuario
End;
End;
```

Imagem ilustrativa do valor do campo:
[Valor desconfigurado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrYOz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Informei abaixo e deu certo esta 100%

```
Set @Token = (Select CONVERT(nvarchar(128), HASHBYTES ('SHA2_512', CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), @RetornaUsuarioId) + @Nome), 1))
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).